# A script in Hibernate/JPQL in Java or in TSQL would be executed faster

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jpql

Just a theoretical question. I want to manipulate a lot of data massively in a production database (Microsoft SQL Server), so the execution time is of great essence as the production database can not be down for very long. 
The script is a little complex and contains for loops.
Running a script using JPA and Hibernate would be faster, or should i prefer a TSQL script and run it directly in the database?

The TSQL loop would still have for loops, so would it make a difference in performance? Would it still be quicker?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the script could do with fewer for-loops than you might think in T-SQL because T-SQL has some very nice solutions to apply manipulations on an entire _set_ of data rather than per-row (as you would in JPQL or any programming language. If you post the script you have and ask how to optimize it there's a lot of expertise on StackOverflow that can help with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mass manipulation of data it is always advisable to run the queries near to the DB itself using `tsql`. Using `jpql` includes overhead of parsing the queries to native DB queries and usually also accounts network delay (may be minute but can play crucial role with large data) due to the fact that generally DB and application doesn't share same server.

Comment: Actually, they don't share the same server, so you are right there surely would be network delay